# compute probability of choose at least one edge correctly in a graph

Tags: probability, combinations

I had a programming exam and encountered a probability question which can’t solve even mathematically.

The question was: if in a graph with V vertices and E edges, we choose E edges (suppose edges are hidden or in other words don’t know stretched between which vertices) then evaluate the probability of chosen at least one correct edge?

I can’t understand the problem correctly (we have E edges and chose E edges!) but here is some example which was given and what I tried

Vertex: 3, chosen edge: 1 --> .3333

Vertex: 3, chosen edge: 2 --> 1.0000

Vertex: 9, chosen edge 6 --> .6951

The formula which I think might  give the correct answer:

(total- 0 correct edge)/total

But that doesn’t work, for instance in third example above

(C(9,6)-C(6,0)C(6,6))/C(9,6)=.9880

Also about second example above I don’t know how that possible to be 1 cause may we chose both edges wrong.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you pick an $E$ edge graph on the given $V$ vertices and check if that graph has at least one edge in common with the given $E$ edge graph.
There are ${V\choose 2}\choose E$ graphs to pick from, and the praphs have *no* edge in common if the $E$ edges are actually picked from the ${V\choose 2}-E$ non-edges. Hence the answer is
$$1-\frac{{V\choose 2}-E\choose E}{{{V\choose 2}\choose E}} $$

Comment: and now my brain is free again :) , thanks.